# What's the difference between username and from in JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail

When sending mail, the username and password should be given to get access to the mail server. And then why "from" is still needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your mail server, you might be allowed to authenticate as one user, but then send mail as several other users.  For example, you might want to log in as yourself and then send out your company newsletter as "newsletter@company.com".

Comment: That means, in some conditions, I can send a mail on behalf of another user, and the receiver will think that the mail is from that user, and can't find any clue at all that the mail is sent from me. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  What you're allowed to do depends on your mail server.  Have you received any spam lately?  :-)